# ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["Backlog"]; me devuelve nulo

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Estoy tratando de subir un archivo excel con extensión .xlsb mediante c# y la librería epplus pero en esta linea de código me devuelve nulo

```
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["Backlog"];
```

Ya comprobé que el directorio exista y el nombre de la hoja de calculo también es la misma

Este es parte de mi código

```
ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo(PathArchivoLog));

// Select the worksheet that you want to read from.
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["Backlog"];
```

Y el nombre de mi archivo excel es este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por favor alguien que me ayude

Comment: El código que has puesto es correcto, el problema debe estar en otro lado. Es una aplicación web ???

Comment: @Yussef si es una aplicación web

Comment: Prueba algo como esto: `FileInfo newFile = new(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()!.Location) + "\\unacarpeta\\otracarpeta\\nombre_excel.xlsx");  ExcelPackage pck = new(newFile);`

Comment: @Yussef sustituyo la linea de codigo que tengo yo  ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo(PathArchivoLog)); por la que me recomienas , pero me pone que la caracteristica de creacion de objetos con tipo destino no esta disponible en c# 5, me recomienda actualizar a la version 9.0 y al querer actualizar no de lo actualiza

Comment: @Yussef alguna otra sugerencia??... Esque como que no me esta leyendo los archivos con extension .xlsb pero los archivos con extension .xls y .xlsx si me los toma, no se si sea por al tipo de extension .xlsb

Comment: Yo sospecho que la ruta del archivo es incorrecta y eso es lo que intentaba probar con el código que te indiqué. Para descartar que sea esto, prueba  con tu mismo código y con una ruta completa y fija, algo como (c:/unacarpeta/otracarpeta/etc/archivo.xlsx) es decir comenzando de la raíz. Si te funciona me avisas para indicarte como solucionarlo con una ruta relativa. Otra cosa es que debes poner `ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;` que no sé si lo has puesto